# What could be the issue with my Tkinter GUI .py file when converted to .exe, generating plot on a canvas no longer works and closes the GUI itself?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, exe

What could be the issue with my Tkinter GUI .py file when converted to .exe file, the function of generating plot on a canvas no longer works and actually closes the GUI itself? The console window is clear from any error or caveats..

I have steered away from using, 'from tkinter import *', already and my .py script runs without any issue in Spyder console or using Jupyter notebook

Comment: Does it have any dependency? Images or file or anything?

Comment: did you use `pyinstaller`?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes, I used pyinstaller script.py.. not sure what adjustments on this could be done..

Comment: Initially, I was loading my saved image plot onto a canvas, but then I changed the script to embedding it directly on the cavas instead. Both works fine in a Python IDE, but when converted to .exe, the function via a button click closes the GUI instead...

Comment: What error shows up in the console.

Comment: The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.

Comment: Not sure if these infos/warnings during the conversion could be the issue:307802 INFO: Excluding import 'matplotlib'
307818 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib._pylab_helpers from module IPython.core.pylabtools
307818 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.pyplot from module IPython.core.pylabtools
307818 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.backend_bases from module IPython.core.pylabtools
307818 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib from module IPython.core.pylabtools
307818 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.figure from module IPython.core.pylabtools638361 INFO:   Matplotlib ba

Comment: 744436 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of c:\programdata\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_ilp64.dll
744636 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of c:\programdata\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_lp64.dll
745136 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of c:\programdata\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.dll
745194 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90rtl.dll dependency of c:\programdata\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
745200 WARNING: lib not found: pgc14.dll dependency of c:\programdata\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll